# Structuring Category List with MySQL on Android

Tags: android, mysql, structure

I'm having a little difficulty structuring a few screens for an app I'm working on and I'm looking for a little insight if possible.

Basically what I'm trying to do is have a list of "categories" in my app. And this is thr structure I would like it to follow. 
Mainscreen -> categories -> items within selected category -> specific item

Now, in my mysql database I made a column named "category" and in the column I would type the name of the categories the item would be under. In the app, I would like the screen to show all of the different categories that show up in the database, and if someone selected the category from the list, it would show all items under that category.

I'm not sure if a column VARCHAR is the way to structure the database for categories, if this doesn't make any sense I'll try to explain further. Thanks for the info.